# how could i publish sonarqube report in jenkins? using the sonarqube portlet

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, portlet

I have configured sonarqube for one of my projects, but now i want to publish the sonarqube details in my jenkins dashboard. what could be the best possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a straight forward way of getting "all" the data from sonar on to your Jenkins dashboard but can actually get a sonar badge and Quality gate info by using the Sonar plugin for Jenkins.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/?q=cache:Tbhy8757pK4J:https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to deploy sonarqube on your local machine, ones it is done, then copy the URL of your sonarqube server, I am assuming, you have deployed sonarqube server on port 9090, once this done, log in to the sonarqube server and then create a project and then generate a token for that project:

Once these above configuration is done, just hit below maven command to generate sonarqube report on the sonarqube server:

**mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=[projectName] -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9090 -Dsonar.login=[tokenId]**

Below is the screenshot, this is how your reports on the sonarqube will looks like:

[image]